# Cant get Open AI API to work, incorrect API key?

Tags: python, pycharm, openai-api

```
import os
import openai

api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
openai.api_key = api_key

prompt = "Translate the following English text to French: 'Hello, how are you?'"
response = openai.Completion.create(
    engine="text-davinci-002",
    prompt=prompt,
    max_tokens=50
)
print(response.choices[0].text.strip())
```

thats the code, and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danim\PycharmProjects\EXAM\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    response = openai.Completion.create(
  File "C:\Users\danim\PycharmProjects\EXAM\venv\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\completion.py", line 25, in create
    return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\danim\PycharmProjects\EXAM\venv\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\abstract\engine_api_resource.py", line 153, in create
    response, _, api_key = requestor.request(
  File "C:\Users\danim\PycharmProjects\EXAM\venv\lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 298, in request
    resp, got_stream = self._interpret_response(result, stream)
  File "C:\Users\danim\PycharmProjects\EXAM\venv\lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 700, in _interpret_response
    self._interpret_response_line(
  File "C:\Users\danim\PycharmProjects\EXAM\venv\lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 765, in _interpret_response_line
    raise self.handle_error_response(
openai.error.AuthenticationError: Incorrect API key provided: "sk-KaNe*****************************************GJo". You can find your API key at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys.
```

in the enviroment i also have this:

PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;OPENAI_API_KEY="(my latest API Key)"

i cannot get it to work, please help

please help!

idk whats wrong

Comment: A wrong API key is a wrong API key. Have you tried to generate another one and try again? You can generate as many keys as you want.

Comment: Yes, and nothing works

Comment: In that case you should consult openAI rather than asking the question here. Closing.